# Printing V shape using recursion only

Tags: java, recursion

I'm trying to print out a shape of the letter V using recursion only. I have seen some of the codes in this website related to my problem, but the majority use loops instead of recursion.

Here's my code:

```
  public class Pattern {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         printPattern(5);
    }
       public static void Pattern(int count, String s) {
        if (count == 0) {
            return;
        }

        System.out.print(s);
        Pattern(count - 1, s);
    }

    public static void upperhalf(int count, int max) {
        if (count == 0) {
            return;
        }

        Pattern(max - count, " ");
        Pattern(count, "* ");

        System.out.println();

        upperhalf(count - 1, max);
    }



    public static void printPattern(int n) {
        upperhalf(n, n);

    }
}
```

Output:

```
 * * * * * 
  * * * * 
   * * * 
    * * 
     *
```

The output I want:

```
  *       *
   *     *
    *   *
     * *
      *
```

Comment: Why do you need this? It's possible to replace loops with recursion but I don't see any natural recursivity in this problem.

Comment: @Olivier I know I could use loops, but I wanted to practice recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of solving it. Replace your two consecutive Pattern calls with this:

```
    Pattern(max - count, " ");
    Pattern(1, "* ");
    Pattern(count - 2, "  ");
    Pattern(1, count > 1 ? "* " : "");
```

(Ie your first Pattern call, then an explicit for a single *, then a few spaces (2 less than in your approach), then the last *).

You also need to change the exit statement slightly:

```
public static void Pattern(int count, String s) {
    if (count <= 0) { // <= instead of ==
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your interested, here is one way to do it by by taking successive substrings.
Here are some key points.

- The starting size is modified to ensure it is odd. This guarantees the V will be uniform.
- The passed string consists of white space followed by an asterisk.  The left asterisk is supplied by the recursive method.
- The indentation is used to properly position the start of the remaining string.

```
        int size = 10;
        String v = " ".repeat((size | 1) - 2) + "*";
        V(v,0);


       public static void V(String v, int indent) {
           System.out.println(" ".repeat(indent)+ "*" + v);
           if (v.isEmpty()) {
               return;
           }
           V(v.substring(2),indent+1);
       }
```